# Tidyverse Solution to get Counts Based on Filtering Different Combinations of Variables

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

```
 Library(tidyverse)
```

Using the code below, I would like to use table() or dplyr to get counts of the Sat variables (Q1Sat,Q2Sat,Q3Sat). However, Q1Sat is related to variable Q1Used, Q2Sat is related to Q2Used, and Q3Sat is related to Q3Used. I would like to filter out "No" within the Used variable for each combination, as well as "No" within the House variable.

So, for example, to calculate the counts for Q1Sat, I need to filter out "No" within both Q1used and House. For Q2Sat, I need to filter out "No" within Q2Used and House, and for Q3 Sat, I have to filter out "No" within Q3Used and House.

Using Tidyverse, what is an easy way to accomplish this? (Least amount of code). I would like to use the most recent version of Tidyverse packages, including the devel version of dplyr, if necessary.

```
Q1Sat<-c("Neutral","Neutral","VSat","Sat","Neutral","Sat","VDis","Sat","Sat","VSat")
Q2Sat<-c("Neutral","VSat","Dis","Dis","VDis","Sat","Sat","VSat","Neutral","Dis")
Q3Sat<-c("Sat","Sat","Diss","Neutral","VSat","VDis","Sat","Sat","Sat","Neutral")
Q3Used<-c("Yes","No","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","No")
Q2Used<-c("Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","No","No","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes")
Q1Used<-c("Yes","Yes","Yes","No","No","Yes","Yes","Yes","No","Yes")
House<-c("Yes","No","Unsure","Yes","Yes","No","Unsure","Unsure","Yes","Yes")

Test<-data_frame(Q1Sat,Q2Sat,Q3Sat,Q1Used,Q2Used,Q3Used,House)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Test %>% 
mutate(q1 = ifelse(Q1Used=="Yes", Q1Sat, NA), 
       q2 = ifelse(Q2Used=="Yes", Q2Sat, NA), 
       q3 = ifelse(Q3Used=="Yes", Q3Sat, NA)) %>% 
select(q1:q3) %>% 
sapply(., table)

$q1

Neutral     Sat    VDis    VSat 
      2       2       1       2 

$q2

    Dis Neutral     Sat    VSat 
      3       2       1       2 

$q3

   Diss Neutral     Sat    VDis    VSat 
      1       1       4       1       1
```

Comment: This looks like kind of what I was looking for since it used Tidyverse. I haven't had a chance to try it out yet, but I don't think you incorporated the "House" component in question? Also, is there a way to avoid the multiple ifelse statements? What about using the new devel version of dplyr's scoped filter function or SE?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(Test)`), reshape it to 'long' by specifying the `patterns` in the `melt`, grouped by 'Qs' and 'Sat', get the count where 'Used' is 'Yes' and reshape it back to 'wide' format

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(Test), measure = patterns("Sat", "Used"), 
   value.name = c("Sat", "Used"), variable.name = 'Qs')[
   Used == "Yes", .N , .(Qs, Sat)], Qs~Sat, fill=0)[, Qs := nm1[Qs][]
#   Qs Dis Diss Neutral Sat VDis VSat
#1: Q1   0    0       2   2    1    2
#2: Q2   3    0       2   1    0    2
#3: Q3   0    1       1   4    1    1
```

---

Also, we can do this more compactly with `base R`

```
un1 <- unique(unlist(Test[1:3]))
t(mapply(function(x,y) table(factor(x[y == "Yes"], levels = un1)), Test[1:3], Test[4:6]))
```

Or even more compactly with

```
table(col(Test[1:3]), unlist(replace(Test[1:3], Test[4:6]!= "Yes", NA)))
#    Dis Diss Neutral Sat VDis VSat
#1   0    0       2   2    1    2
#2   3    0       2   1    0    2
#3   0    1       1   4    1    1
```

Comment: I was hoping for each variable separately, like the answer below. Also, does this take into account the "House" variable? I wanted to filter against "no" in the Used variables as well as the House variable.

Comment: I like the compact code, but is there a way to use the new scoped dplyr filter functions together with SE somehow? I can ask it as a new question if it's easier...I believe the Tidyverse method involves multiple nested if_else's, but is there a way to avoid this with scoped filtering and SE from the devel version of dplyr?